# Replace every word with tag

Tags: java, javascript, android

**JAVASCRIPT or JAVA solution needed**

The solution I am looking for could use java or javascript. I have the html code in a string so I could manipulate it before using it with java or afterwards with javascript.

***problem***

Anyway, I have to wrap each word with a tag. For example:

```
<html> ... >
Hello every one, cheers
< ... </html>
```

should be changed to

```
<html> ... >
<word>Hello</word> <word>every</word> <word>one</word>, <word>cheers</word>
< ... </html>
```

---

**Why?**

This will help me use javascript to select/highlight a word. It seems the only way to do it is to use the function highlightElementAtPoint which I added in the **JAVASCRIPT hint**: It simply finds the element of a certain x,y coordinate and highlights it. I figured that if every word is an element, it will be doable.

The idea is to use this approach to allow us to detect highlighted text in an android WebView even if that would mean to use a twisted highlighting method. Think a bit more and you will find many other applications for this.

---

**JAVASCRIPT hint**

I am using the following code to highlight a word; however, this will highlight the whole text belonging to a certain tag. When each word is a tag, this will work to some extent. If there is a substitute that will allow me to highlight a *word* at a certain position, it would also be a solution.

```
function highlightElementAtPoint(xOrdinate, yOrdinate) {
    var theElement = document.elementFromPoint(xOrdinate, yOrdinate);
    selectedElement = theElement;
    theElement.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    var theName = theElement.nodeName;
    var theArray = document.getElementsByTagName(theName);
    var theIndex = -1;
    for (i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++) {
        if (theArray[i] == theElement) {
            theIndex = i;
        }
    }
    window.androidselection.selected(theElement.innerHTML);
    return theName + " " + theIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try to use something like

```
String yourStringHere = yourStringHere.replace(" ", "</word> <word>" )
yourStringHere.replace("<html></word>", "<html>" );//remove first closing word-tag
```

Should work, maybe u have to change sth...

Comment: Actually, `.replace(" ", "</word> <word>" )` only replaces once. You have to use a RegEx

Comment: There is replaceAll which replaces every occurence of the regex

Answer (score 4):

```
var tags = document.body.innerText.match(/\w+/g);
for(var i=0;i<tags.length;i++){
    tags[i] = '<word>' + tags[i] + '</word>';
}
```

Or as @ThomasK said:

```
var tags = document.body.innerText;
tags = '<word>' + tags + '</word>';
tags = tags.replace(/\s/g,'</word><word>');
```

But you have to keep in mind: `.replace(" ",foo)` only replaces the space once. For multiple replaces you have to use `.replace(/\s+/g,foo)`

And as @ajax333221 said, the second way will include commas, dots and other symbols, so the better solution is the first

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/c6ftq/4/

Comment: I am not really into javascript. But this does not seem to work although in theory splitting should work. Could it be that document.body.innerText does not access all the text inside other nodes. Maybe child nodes should be traversed and all their innertext split and fixed?

Comment: The first example will include the commas and other stuff that probably OP don't want (based on this input/output example)

Comment: I do not use javascript so sorry again but can you please check what is happening http://jsfiddle.net/8SrmP/

Comment: In this case, the browser understands that `<word>foo</word>` is a text, not a `word` tag with the `foo` content

Comment: I meant why is the image removed?

Comment: I still don't know, but I'll check it

Answer (score 2):

```
inputStr = inputStr.replaceAll("(?<!</?)\\w++(?!\\s*>)","<word>$0</word>");
```

Comment: may i ask if this regex will work on java and javascript aswell?

Comment: @SherifelKhatib: Tested in java. i guess, javascript does not support look behind.

Comment: thank you.. it does work but it ruins much of the formatting +1

Comment: the string is actually html so it has tags like <p> and <b> and whatever. The regex for some reason removes images and much of the text  now has a stroke.

Answer (score 2):

You can try following code,

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class myTag 
{
    static String startWordTag = "<Word>";
    static String endWordTag = "</Word>";
    static String space = " ";

    static String myText = "Hello how are you ";

    public static void main ( String args[] )
    {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer (myText," ");

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        while ( st.hasMoreTokens() )
        {
            sb.append(startWordTag); 
            sb.append(st.nextToken());
            sb.append(endWordTag);
            sb.append(space);
        }

        System.out.println ( "Result:" + sb.toString() );
    }
}
```

Comment: @SherifelKhatib , sure it will work, just give me a sample tag text or you can try your self in the variable `myText` by yourself.

Comment: it is common to find something like `<p>Hi Lucifier</p>`

Comment: you mean my answer doesn't suitable to your requirement ?